# Create SQL Server database with defined file size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, localdb

I want to create a `.mdf` SQL Server database file with defined file size of 512 KB:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=master");

if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
     connection.Open();

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE thedb ON PRIMARY (NAME='thedb', FILENAME='r:\thedb.mdf', SIZE = 512KB, " + 
     "MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 500KB) LOG ON (NAME ='thedb_log', FILENAME = 'r:\thedb_log.ldf', SIZE = 512KB)";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is creating a `.mdf` file with a size of 8 MB and a `.ldf` file with 64.5 MB (!)...

If I omit `LOG ON`, then the size of the `.ldf` file is also 8 MB.

Comment: The database files cannot be smaller than the model database. Look at its content and try to shrink it beforehand.

Comment: To complement what @Alejandro said, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver), on SQL Server 2016 and later, the model database is 8MB. It was 1MB before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&tabs=sqlserver):

> When size is not supplied for the primary file, the Database Engine
>   uses the size of the primary file in the model database. The default
>   size of model is 8 MB (beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) or 1 MB
>   (for earlier versions). When a secondary data file or log file is
>   specified, but size is not specified for the file, the Database Engine
>   makes the file 8 MB (beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) or 1 MB
>   (for earlier versions). The size specified for the primary file must
>   be at least as large as the primary file of the model database.

Check the size of the model DB mdf file. Your new DB cannot be smaller than that. If the number for the initial file size is too small, it looks like it defaults to 8MB. You may be able to reduce the size of the model DB to get a DB smaller than 8MB.

You are probably creating a file that is too small for SQL Server to function properly. If you are looking for small single-file DBs you might look into [SQLLite](https://sqlite.org/about.html).

Comment: Thank you, SQLite is what I was searching for, although it's not server based. I tried to resize `model.mdf` with `ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE`. It didn't pan out, but it's not important anymore.

Comment: @MHN - Glad I could help. You didn't specify how you were using the DB so I guessed you were doing something embedded or on limited hardware so server-based would not be important. MS used to have SQL CE which might work, but it is deprecated. SQL Express will give you the same issues as full SQL Server. If you really want a small file footprint and a server-based SQL server, you can also check out MariaDB/MySQL. The empty DB files are pretty small.

Answer (score 2):

When doing a [create database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql) that new database is created based on the [model database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database). See [The model Database and Creating New Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql#the-model-database-and-creating-new-databases). When [defining a size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql#arguments) for a new database, that size is ignored if it is smaller than the model database:

> The size specified for the primary file must be at least as large as the primary file of the model database.

Since the model database is 8MB, the default (and smallest) size for any new database is also 8MB.

To have a smaller file size [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql) can be performed on the model database. The smallest size allowed is 3MB.

```sql
use model;
dbcc shrinkfile(modeldev, 3)
```

from: https://github.com/SimonCropp/LocalDb#template-database-size